# How to use where clause on case statement result

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

```
CREATE TABLE case_in_where 
(
      id integer PRIMARY KEY,
      name text NOT NULL
);
  
INSERT INTO case_in_where (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz');
```

I want to filter data but `namevalue` is working with the order by not with where condition how to fix this? you can try here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d3b4/62

```
SELECT 
    id, name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN name = 'foo' THEN true
        WHEN name = 'bar' THEN false
        ELSE NULL
    END AS namevalue
FROM 
    case_in_where
WHERE
    namevalue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    namevalue
```

Comment: Exactly, the WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the column alias is created. Repeat the case _expression_, or use a derived table or cte.

Comment: That's standard sql, sadly enough.  Some RDBMSs allow you to filter by aliases, but not postgresql.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f7f6/1 seems to work how I would expect, by listing `c` in the order of `false`, `true`, `null`.

Comment: @Andrew, if you do a GROUP BY, a column alias in the WHERE clause could be a bit unintuitive.

Comment: As a side note: it's a CASE _expression_, not a (complete) statement

Comment: @jarlh repeat a case expression how? can u give an example query

Comment: Simply copy the case expression from SELECT and paste it into the WHERE clause. However, I'd go with the derived table solution.

Comment: @sahil - Literally, write the expression twice... `SELECT id, name, CASE WHEN blah blah END AS namevalue FROM table WHERE CASE WHEN blah blah END IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as embedded into the `FROM` clause and move the `WHERE` clause out. There are other options too, notably a CTE as @jarlh noted.

```sql
select * from
(
 SELECT id, name, CASE 
  WHEN name = 'foo' THEN true
  WHEN name = 'bar' THEN false
  ELSE NULL
  END AS namevalue
 FROM case_in_where
) t
where namevalue is not NULL
order by namevalue;
```

Comment: Aka a _derived table_.

Comment: @jarlh Exactly, I quoted you in the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the terminology. (A subquery like this in the FROM clause is called a derived table.)

Comment: thanks for the info guys, @jarlh as u mentioned where clause runs before the case statement that's why this query failing right?

Comment: @sahil - This answer shouldn't be failing.  The scope of the `WHERE` clause and aliases is different.  The `()`'s screate a scope allowing the aliases to be created, and then later on the outer query's `WHERE` clause is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using sub-query which you can do something like below:

```
Select * from (
  SELECT id, name, CASE 
  WHEN name = 'foo' THEN true
  WHEN name = 'bar' THEN false
  ELSE NULL
  END AS namevalue
FROM case_in_where ) t
where namevalue IS NOT NULL
 order by namevalue
```

you can also use CTE(Common Table Expression) as below.

Common Table Expression: Also called as CTE, is a temporary named result set that you can reference within a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement. The CTE can also be used in a View.

```
With tmp AS (SELECT id, name, 
  CASE WHEN name = 'foo' THEN true
  WHEN name = 'bar' THEN false
  ELSE NULL END  namevalue
FROM case_in_where
 )

select * from tmp
where namevalue is not NULL
order by namevalue;
```

If you want to read more about CTE, you can read here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/

We do not use newly created column with CASE expression as alias in the WHERE clause. For Order By, you can do the following but again you won't be able to use  NULL condition in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, name, 
  CASE WHEN name = 'foo' THEN true
  WHEN name = 'bar' THEN false
  ELSE NULL END  namevalue
FROM case_in_where
 order by 3 desc;
```

I hope this clarifies your confusion.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Thank you. Added the same. :)